Use a string value from a CTE in an IN-clause in a simple SQL query
I am trying to make a simple SQL query in PostgreSQL to use in our team:
with findData as (
  select '(''XXX'',''YYYY'')' as dataList
)
select * from findData

That gives the result:
('XXX','YYYY')

Exactly what I wanted !
But I want to use it like this in a simple SQL script:
select t.variabel1,
       t.variabel2
from myTable t
where t.variabel3 in (select dataList from findData);

But this doesn't work ...
Has my problem a solution?

That's not a simple question. Strings aren't lists of values, they're a single string value whose interpretation is up to the user or developer.  Where do XXX and YYY come from? What are you trying to do?

The datalist is treated as a single string value, currently. So, to use the 'IN', you need them seperate. Can be done like this.
with findData as (
    select unnest(array['XXX', 'YYYY']) as dataList
)
select t.variabel1, t.variabel2
from myTable t
where t.variabel3 in (select dataList from findData);

The unnest function is used to expand the array into rows.

Thank you very very much drk1rd - select unnest(array['XXX', 'YYYY']) as dataList - was the solution. You made my day :) !

The simplest way is probably to use an array and use = ANY instead f IN:
SELECT ...
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE t.variabel3 = ANY (ARRAY['XXX','YYYY']);

